# Аналог switch, но для goto/from label (MATLAB Simulink R2022b)

Tags: matlab

Есть такая ситуация: при определенных условиях (if1 - if6) нужно пробросить сигнал с меток From(HIN1-3, LIN1-3) на VTx, как показано на фото. 
Метки From для каждого из условий будут одинаковы (HIN/LIN для каждого из блоков if action subsystem), отличаются только метки Goto. 
Как можно грамотно реализовать эту идею?
[image: Пример]